# Trying to create disappearing squares in Java

Tags: java, swing

```
class GraphicsExampleComponent extends JComponent

{
    //@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        //make the first call to your recursive routine
    drawSquare1(g, 0, 0, 80);
        
    }
  public void drawSquare1(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size)
    {
    //draw a rectangle
     g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
     g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);


    //reset the parameters
    x = x + size + 10;
    y = y + (size/4);
    size = size/4;

    //determine if you should call it again. 
        if (size<4 || x>600)
      drawSquare1(g, x, y, size);
    }
```

My assignment is to create disappearing squares that get 25% smaller as they move to the right. When I run the code, it just creates the one square and stops. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe check the values of `size` and `x` before `if (size<4 || x>600)`. They don't seem to meet that condition.

Comment: You invoke the drawSquare(...) method with the same parameters each time. So the square will always be painted at the same size in the same location. You need 1) a Swing Timer to schedule the animation 2) every time the Timer fires you need to update the x/y location and size of the square.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` to update the state of your squares and repaint the component

Answer (score 3):

> disappearing squares that get 25% smaller as they move to the right.

Ok, let's step back for a second and break this down a bit.

You need to know...

- The amount of space to be covered
- The amount of space already covered (by the square)
- The original size of the square
- The size of the square should be when it reaches the other side (25% smaller)

When you have all this, you can calculate the size of the square at any point along its journey.

To determine the amount of space, you can use the component's width, via `getWidth()`.

To determine the space already covered, you could start by having a look at box's current x position

```
// Assuming that box is a instance of Rectangle
double progress = (double)box.x / (double)getWidth();
```

We could argue that we should look at the middle of the box, or the trailing edge, but both of those are easy to implement.

Next, we need know the range of change (from start to end size), we can then use that to calculate the delta to be applied to the box...

```
double range = startSize - endSize;
double value = (range * progress);

box.width = (int)startSize - (int)value;
box.height = (int)startSize - (int)value;
```

Soooo, this will provide with the means to determine the size of the component based on it's current location (horizontally) through the component.

Next, you need some way to update the box's position and update the UI.

One of the better solutions is to use a Swing `Timer`.  This will allow you to perform a repeating action (with a specified delay between updates) which won't block the UI and will generate updates within the Event Dispatching Queue, which is important because Swing is not Thread safe.

Have a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

And finally, all we need, is to update the component with current state, via it's `paintComponent` method ... easy :P

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static double startSize = 50;
        protected static double endSize = startSize * 0.25;

        private Rectangle box;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            box = new Rectangle(0, 100 - 25, 50, 50);
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (box.x + box.width >= getWidth()) {
                        box.x = getWidth() - box.width;
                        box.width = (int)endSize;
                        box.height = (int)endSize;

                        timer.stop();

                        repaint();
                    }
                    box.x += 1;
                    double progress = (double)box.x / (double)getWidth();

                    double range = startSize - endSize;
                    double value = (range * progress);

                    box.width = (int)startSize - (int)value;
                    box.height = (int)startSize - (int)value;

                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            box.x = 0;
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fill(box);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition `if (size < 4 || x>600)` is never true because when `drawSquare1` is invoked for the first time `size=80` and `x=0`. 
Changing it to say `if (size > 4 && x<600)` will paint 3 squares on the screen without any noticeable animation. 
To animate it we'll need to add some delay between paintings and remove previously painted squares. 
To do so we use a swing Timer. We use the timer to repeatedly invoke `drawSquare1`.
`drawSquare1` should modify the parameters controlling the painting, and call repaint.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    Main() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        GraphicsExampleComponent board = new GraphicsExampleComponent();
        frame.add(board);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        board.animate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}

class GraphicsExampleComponent extends JComponent{

    private final static int W = 200, H = 100, MIN_SIZE = 4, STEP = 10, DELAY = 2000;
    private int x= 0, y = 0, size = 80;
    private Timer timer;

    void animate(){
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, e->drawSquare());
        timer.start();
    }

    public void drawSquare(){

        //check stop criteria 
        if (size < MIN_SIZE ||  x >= getWidth()) {
            timer.stop();
            return;
        }

        //reset the parameters
        x = x + size + STEP;
        y = y + size/4;
        size = size/4;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //draw a rectangle
        g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
        g.dispose();;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension preferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(W, H);
    }
}
```

---

(Test in online [here](https://replit.com/@c0derrepo/AnimatedSqures#Main.java))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help. I unfortunately could not use a timer due to us not learning about it in class and we are not allowed to use methods/codes that we haven't gone over. To fix this I had to fix my base case by making it size >= 4 && x < 600.